# not able to output mm-dd-yyyy in select statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

In MYSQL database e_date is stored as a yyyy-mm-dd format but i want expiry_date output as a mm-dd-yyyy format below is my query statement but it outputs me a wrong date.

```
SELECT u.u_name,u.u_id,cn.cell_num,max(trans.expiry) as expiry_date from users u, cell_num cn,
(select t.u_id_fk, t.e_date as expiry from connections c, trans_tbl t,users u where 
c.v_lan_id=t.vlanconfk and u.u_id = t.u_id_fk and u.u_id not in ( select u_id FROM ( SELECT count(1) 
c , t.u_id_fk u_id , case when t.e_date <=date(now()+interval 9 hour) Then 1 else 0 end exp from 
trans_tbl t Group by t.u_id_fk, case when t.e_date <=date(now()+interval 9 hour) Then 1 else 0 end 
)act where act.exp =0 )) AS trans
WHERE 
u.u_id=trans.u_id_fk AND u.u_id=cn.u_id_fk
GROUP BY u.u_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DATE_FORMAT` to reformat the date:

```
SELECT u.u_name, u.u_id, cn.cell_num,
       DATE_FORMAT(MAX(trans.expiry), '%m-%d-%Y') AS expiry_date
FROM users u, -- ...
```

Comment: I was going to edit out the trailing comma in your answer Nick `AS expiry_date,` <, seeing the OP doesn't have it in theirs. I just wasn't sure, and didn't want to take the chance. If you feel it should stay, then I'll just let sleeping dogs lay.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner you were right. I've removed it. Thanks for pointing it out